# CakePHP blackholes file uploads when post_max_size is exceeded

Tags: php, file-upload, cakephp-2.3, csrf-protection

As stated in the corresponding [PHP manual entry](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size), PHP will clear out `$_POST` and `$_FILES` if an upload exceeds the `post_max_size` limit.

I have a form like the following, and I'm using the `Security` component:

```
echo $this->Form->create(false, array('type' => 'file', 'action' => '...'));
echo $this->Form->file('documentFile');
echo $this->Form->end('Upload');
```

Now when I upload a large file exceeding said limit, I get "The request has been black-holed" due to CSRF validation failing - which is not surprising, since PHP clearing out `$_POST` also removes the CSRF protection token.

I can use `Security->unlockedActions` to work around this, but it doesn't seem ideal (and I'll lose CSRF protection). Is there any way to prevent the black-holing in this case?

**Edit:** I don't consider increasing `post_max_size` a solution - it just increases the file size required to trigger the black-holing, but doesn't solve the core problem.

Comment: increase the post_max_size

Comment: @nathanhayfield but that's also more of a workaround, right?

Comment: not if your goal is to upload larger files.

Comment: Oh right, maybe should have clarified this. My goal is to show a meaningful error message to the user instead of black-holing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, just found the solution myself.

I added the following to my `AppController::beforeFilter()`:

```
if (
   ($this->request->isPost() || $this->request->isPut()) &&
   empty($_POST) && empty($_FILES)
) {
    $this->Security->csrfCheck = false;
}
```

Maybe this is of use to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

One possible problem is that your upload_max_filesize is too low in your PHP.ini. I get the CSRF error when it's too low and an empty array when I pr($this->request->data);

Upping the limit to something reasonable has fixed this issue for me.

Comment: Well but this is not a complete solution. Let's say I set the limit to 2 Gb. A user can still go ahead and try to upload a file > 2 Gb (setting aside script execution time limit settings etc.), which will trigger the blackholing again. It's rather hypothetical, I know, but I was looking for a definitive solution - and found it (see my own answer).